# How can I concat two objects with different structure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two objects that look like this:

```
var a = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Zero"
}];
var b = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "one",
    firstName: "First"
}],
    [{
        id: 2,
        name: "two",
        firstName: "Second"
    }], [{
        id: 3,
        name: "three",
        firstName: "Third"
    }];
```

I want to concat the two objects in Javascript to look something like this:

```
var c = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Zero"
}],
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: "one",
        firstName: "First"
    }], [{
        id: 2,
        name: "two",
        firstName: "Second"
    }], [{
        id: 3,
        name: "three",
        firstName: "Third"
    }];
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you reclarify the structures you have/wish to have - what you've posted isn't valid syntax

Comment: what exactly c and b are? you do realize c equals only to the first array , all the others array has no meaning. assuming this doesn't throw exception at the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although what you've posted doesn't look valid, your objects are in arrays so you can use `.concat`

```
var a = [{id: 0, name: "Zero"}];
var b = [
    [{id: 1, name: "one", firstName:"First"}], 
    [{id: 2, name: "two", firstName:"Second"}], 
    [{id: 3, name: "three", firstName: "Third"}]
];

var c = a.concat(b);
```

if there is no reason why your objects are in individual arrays, you'd want `b` to be:

```
var b = [
    {id: 1, name: "one", firstName:"First"}, 
    {id: 2, name: "two", firstName:"Second"}, 
    {id: 3, name: "three", firstName: "Third"}
];
```